# How to update many rows and from Select sub query and get value for where too in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, select

I want to update 10000 rows from Select when I have the value for where condition coming from same select sub query. E.g.

```
UPDATE TableA A 
SET col1 = @val1, col2 = @val2
WHERE col3 = @val3;
 All @val value I get from SELECT statement.
SELECT @val1, @val2, @val3 From TableB B
WHERE B.Key = (condition).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableA A 
JOIN TableB B
ON B.val3 = A.col3
SET A.col1 = b.val1, 
    A.col2 = b.val2
WHERE B.Key = (condition)
```

Comment: I understand your query but I get all values from Select statement and I do not know how to pass values from Select Statement.

Comment: TableB is joined to TableA in the query, and that's where it's getting the values. You could use a select, but as long as you can define the condition to match up the source and destination rows in the two tables, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to solve my problem.
I am quite not sure if this is the simplest solution but works for me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
  DECLARE val1 INT;
  DECLARE val2 VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE val3 VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT val1,val2, val3 FROM table_A
WHERE = (condition);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cursor_i;
 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO val1,val2, val3;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    UPDATE TableA A
    SET A.valA1 = val1, A.valA2 = val2
    WHERE A.valA3 = val3;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
;;
```